# centering img's in div

Tags: html, css

I create x img tags from javascript inside divMyAbilities and would like them centered to the div. I thought margin: auto would do that but it doesn't. How can I get these images all lined up from left to right but centered to the div? Honestly I can code in 20 different languages but css just doesn't register with me.

```
<div id="abilities" style="width: 600px; height: 75px; background-color: red;">
    <div id="divMyAbilities" style="margin: auto;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: avoid using `styles` and instead use CSS classes.

Comment: try using `text-align:center` on the div to auto centre `inline` contents

Comment: C++, C, C#, VB6, VBA, VBScript, DOS Scripting, VB.NET, Javascript, Java, Lua, Pearl, PHP, Python. OK, maybe 14 :)

Comment: haha, that's about ten more than me.... and lol @ DOS, old skool.... I was a dab hand a QBasic

Comment: That worked. I guess I wouldn't have thought text-align would align anything but...text :)